# Injecting multiple services into an angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have made an angular library and i am trying to import couple of services and constants file into the library. however, when i built, i get the error that the services and constants file should be under 'rootDir' of the library. is there any solution/approach on how we can import these files which are under main application src folder into the library and build it successfully ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question , can you give me some glimpse of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to inject something from application to your library, do it this way:

```
export class LibraryModule {
  static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibraryModule,
      providers: [{provide: 'config', useValue: config}]
    };
  }
}
```

then use the injected class like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './app-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-test.component.css']
})
export class AppTestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( @Inject('config') config) {
   // use the injected 
 }
}
```

How to enable injection in application module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, LibraryModule.forRoot(supposeToInject)  ],
  providers:    [ Logger ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

U will have to make sure that your services are decorated with below

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for answering a question too! It would probably be more helpful if you explain what your code snippet does to help people understand.